# Problems running react js in java spring mvc

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning to use React and wanted to use it in a SpringBoot application, but I just can't seem to get this working.
I can create a website using Spring-MVC and also execute JavaScript code on it (without React, JSX). But I just can't figure out how to use JavaScript code that uses React.

**What I got working so far is...**

- A website with a Spring-MVC backend
- Executing javascript code on this website
- Building a jar of the application using maven
- Creating a React project inside my spring project using the *create-react-app* tool
- Compiling the React code using a maven plugin (following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/including-react-in-your-spring-boot-maven-build-ae3b8f8826e)) (or at least I think it's working, because maven says that the build is successfull)
- Loading the React js script in the browser

**What is not working is...**

- Executing the React js script in the browser or debugging the script

---

The simple React code I want to execute looks like this: *test.js*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function TestComponent() {
    return <div>
        <p>Hello There!</p>
    </div>;
}

debugger;

ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('hello_there'));
alert("Hello There!");
```

It should just add some text into the html file to show it's working, but it doesn't. The html (thymeleaf) file looks like this: *home.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Go Server - JFabricationGames</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JFG - Go Server (WIP)</h1>
    <img th:src="@{images/welcome.png}" width=500 />
    <br>
    <a th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>

    <div id="hello_there"></div>
    <div id="hello_there_2"></div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="test_no_react.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

And my Spring project looks like this:

[image: Spring project structure]

and is build using this *pom.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.jfabricationgames</groupId>
    <artifactId>go_server_spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>go_server_spring</name>
    <description>A Go Server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <frontend-src-dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/app</frontend-src-dir>
        <node.version>v12.3.1</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.16.0</yarn.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.7.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn-install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>build-frontend</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>position-react-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${frontend-src-dir}/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you want to have a look at the full project code you can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/tfassbender/go_server_spring/tree/react_test_2

---

Now when opening the website in the browser (firefox 72.0.2 (64-Bit)) and using the developer tools I can see that the script was loaded and I can even see the script code:

[image: Firefox developer tools - network]

But what is strange is that I can't seem to debugg the file or even find the file in the debugger...

[image: Firefox developer tools - debugger]

... although it is loaded and even seems to be executed, because the developer tools show an error in the first line of the script (in the image above).
And what is also kind of strange to me is that the script (test.js) that I can see in the browser (when opening it from the network tab of the developer tools) shows exactly the react code from the *test.js* file. I would expect it to be compiled to ES5, but I'm very new to React so I don't realy know if this is a problem or an expected behaviour.

So basically the problem is that I can't debugg my javascript/React code and I'm not shure whether I load the correct file or even compiled it correctly (because I'm realy new to React). In fact I have no idea what's going on here and what the problem might be.
So any help would be great.

Comment: I have cloned your project, but there is no JSX, no `frontend-maven-plugin`, no React.

Comment: Maybe you checked out the wrong branch? It's on the branch **react_test_2**. The master branch is quite empty till now.

Comment: My bad, didn't switch branch after cloning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that you want to run the javascript output by *create-react-app* on the build, but actually, you're just running a static file `test.js` which is in the `src/main/app/public` directory.

This `test.js` file is not touched by *create-react-app* at all, so you're right that it's not being compiled to ES5, it's simply being served statically as it is. The error you're seeing in Firefox is exactly because of that - it can't handle the `import` statements (fixing this directly is a separate issue which I won't get into here, but essentially you won't have this problem with the *create-react-app* compiled code because it'll be bundled and transpiled to ES5).

Only the code with the entry point at `src/main/app/src/index.js` will be compiled by *create-react-app* and indeed it is, and then as per your `pom.xml` configuration is then copied into `target/classes/static/static/{bundle files}.js`.

What you want to do is link to those *create-react-app* generated bundle files, instead of this `test.js` file. Whatever React code those built bundles contain will run just fine. It's unclear what the role of `test.js` is here, but to conclude, it's simply not being compiled at all and that's the cause of the error, nothing to do with React per se. You should just delete it and link instead to your *create-react-app* generated bundles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'm much closer to achieving what I need now. I now can execute and see the test code of the `test.js` file when adding it to `index.js`. But I'm still not shure how to add the `bundle files` into my spring / thymeleaf html files, because the bundle files are generated and I don't know the names of the generated files. Is there any way for adding the bundle files to other html files or are they only compiled to the index.html file?

Comment: Right - as far as I know they are indeed only output to the built index.html file - I guess to write them into another file you could manually parse them out of index.html and write them into your custom html file, as part of your build script. `exec-maven-plugin` might be a decent way to do this, with a script, following the create-react-app build.